# Display/filter elements based on values from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a webpage that displays results based on the checkbox(filters) values. I'm able to push the values in arrays when user selects them but can't get my head around as to how to actually filter elements based on those values

```
filterA: 
     - London - Hong-Kong - Oxford - New York - Toronto 
filterB:
    - BMW, - Nissan, - GTA, - Toyota, - Honda

const areas = ['London', 'Oxford', 'New York'] // contains checked values from the filterA checkbox
const cars = ['BMW', 'Toyota', 'Honda'] // contains checked values from the filterB
```

Example Div element to be filtered/displayed if London and BMW is checked:

```
 <div class="list-item" data-area="London">
    <span class="car">BMW</span>
    This BMW car is in London
 </div>
```

I want to write something like:

```
if(document.querySelector('div[data-area]') === areas && document.querySelector('.car') === cars  ){
 // filter elements that has 'checked cars' in the 'checked areas'
 // array value can be one item or multiple as its based on users' input
}
```

Please advise. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const areas = ['London', 'Oxford', 'New York'] // contains checked values from the filterA 
const cars = ['BMW', 'Toyota', 'Honda'] // contains checked values from the filterB

function extractCar(element) {
  return element.querySelector('.car').innerHTML;
}

var filter   = Array.prototype.filter,
    result   = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-area]'),
    filtered = filter.call(result, node => areas.includes(node.dataset.area) && cars.includes(extractCar(node)));

console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<div class="list-item" data-area="London">
    <span class="car">BMW</span>
    This BMW car is in London
 </div>
 
 <div class="list-item" data-area="Shanghai">
    <span class="car">BMW</span>
    This BMW car is in London
 </div>
 
  <div class="list-item" data-area="Oxford">
    <span class="car">Honda</span>
    This BMW car is in London
 </div>
```

Comment: great. That's the one. How do I go about tweaking it if one of the arrays is empty i.e user doesn't select anything in the filterA or filterB?
It should return the elements based on available array values if one of the arrays is empty.

Comment: `!areas || areas.includes(...)` would be one option. There are numerous permutations of possibilities. You are going to have to read up on JS a little to be able to make all the adjustments you are going to want to make.

Comment: great. just applied if conditions and it worked! [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/croninja/98rv65w1/1/)
Just one last thing. I'm trying to edit the code to make it work so even if there are more than one car, it still matches. I tried to replace innerHTML with 'includes/indexOf' but still stuck. please check the JSfiddle link to help out.

Comment: Yeah, that is more tricky. You'll have to play around with [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Give it a try and if you can't figure it out, feel free to ask a new question including what you've tried.

Comment: just had a go with 'some'. apparently working fine. Could you just double check when you get a chance. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/croninja/98rv65w1/27/)